# No command supplied, defaulting to serve Vapor

Tags: vapor

I want to create simple data base model. I'am using postgresql-provider package major:1 minor:1. I've followed instructions to create model. I've added preparations and resource to my Droplet object. Message I receive after running is

No command supplied, defaulting to serve...
Database prepared
Server 'default' starting at 0.0.0.0:8080

Can someone help me with the problem?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to fix?

Answer (score 3):

With regards to the message `No command supplied, defaulting to serve`, this is because the binary executable is expecting a 'command'.

```
vapor run [command]
.build/[configuration]/App [command]
```

There are a variety of commands available, such as `vapor run prepare` to run your database preparations, or `vapor run serve` to begin the HTTP server. You can even [add your own commands](https://vapor.github.io/documentation/guide/commands.html).

When the executable is run without any commands, it assumes you *meant* to run the `serve` command, which is the meaning of your messsage `No command supplied, defaulting to serve`.

To suppress this, simply use `vapor run serve` or `.build/[configuration]/App serve` to run your Vapor project.

Answer (score 2):

Notice how it said in the message `Database prepared`. That is because all the tables you've specified in your models already exist.

If you've made changes to your models, you'll first need to revert your changes. Vapor has a set of commands just for preparing a database.

`vapor run prepare --revert`

and

`vapor run prepare`

The --revert one will run whatever code you've put in the revert function on your models (usually people just delete the table), and then the other command will run the prepare functions and create your models' tables from scratch again.